# Error con tipos de dato en Java al compilar

Tags: java, compilar

Tengo un problema al tratar de compilar este ejercicio en Java, utilizo la consola para compilar y el error que me arroja es algo similar a esto: No se puede convertir el tipo de dato String a String[][] ¿Cómo debería entonces hacer las declaraciones?

```
/*
    Crea un programa que cree un array de 5x5 caracteres, lo rellene con puntos, 
    excepto la segunda fila, que estará rellena de letras "A" y luego muestra el 
    contenido del array en pantalla. Deberá aparecer algo como: 
    ..... 
    AAAAA 
    ..... 
    ..... 
    .....
*/
    class ejercicio58 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[][] m = new String[5][5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    if(i==1) 
                        m[j] = "A";
                    else 
                        m[j] = ".";
                }
                if(i==1) 
                    m[i] = "A";
                else
                    m[i] = ".";
            }
            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
                System.out.print(m[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
                    System.out.print(m[j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }       
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema es que el array de string que has creado es de 2 dimensiones (5x5) y en las asignaciones lo tomas como si fuera de uno.
Por ejemplo, en la primera asignación que haces, dentro de los for:

```
if(i==1) 
    m[j] = "A";
else 
    m[j] = ".";
```

te faltaría la i:

```
if(i==1) 
    m[i][j] = "A";
else 
    m[i][j] = ".";
```

Te pasa lo mismo cuando quieres imprimirlo.
Pruébalo y me cuentas ;)
Un saludo.

Comment: Excelente @Miguelw ese era el problema de compilación. Luego tuve que corregir un poco la lógica. Muchas gracias por la colaboración amigo!

Comment: ¡Para eso estamos! Para cualquier otra cosa que no salga de ninguna manera, no dudes es escribir :)

Answer (score 2):

Para asignar un valor a un arreglo bidimensional, tienes que indicar en qué fila y columna va el valor.

Ejemplo:

La primera columna del array, que se encuentra en [0], se llenaría así:

```
m[0][0] = "."; //Fila 1  columna 1
m[1][0] = "A"; //Fila 2, columna 1
m[2][0] = "."; //Fila 3, columna 1
m[3][0] = "."; //Fila 4, columna 1
m[4][0] = "."; //Fila 5, columna 1
```

La segunda columna, que se encuentra en [1],:

```
m[0][1] = "."; //Fila 1  columna 2
m[1][1] = "A"; //Fila 2, columna 2
m[2][1] = "."; //Fila 3, columna 2
m[3][1] = "."; //Fila 4, columna 2
m[4][1] = "."; //Fila 5, columna 2
```

etc.

Entonces, en un bucle for sería:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class ArregloCinco 
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
   // Crear array 5 x 5
    String[][] m = new String[5][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
            //Fila 2
            if (i==1) {
                m[i][j] = "A";
            }else{
                m[i][j] = ".";

            }
        }
    }

    //Imprimir
    for (String[] array : m) 
    {
        for (String element : array)
        {
                System.out.print(element);
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

**Resultado**

> ```
> . . . . . 
> A A A A A 
> . . . . . 
> . . . . . 
> . . . . .
> ```

Comment: Excelente amigo, gracias por la colaboración!

Comment: De nada @PedroFumero Me alegro de que se haya resuelto. Saludos.